# Pass an argument to callback in MathJax 2.7.1

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am calling the `Typeset` method as in code below. Right now, I have  the callback function without any arguments and this works without any problems. However, I would prefer to pass an argument to the callback function of `typeSetDone` rather than use a global variable called `scripts` in the callback function.

**Question** : Is it possible to pass an argument to a callback function in this situation, and if yes then how would I pass it?

```
var scripts =  [];

function someMethod()
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element, typeSetDone]);
}
function typeSetDone() {
   //do something here using the global scripts variable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to queue the function right afterwards, e.g.,

```
var scripts =  [];

function someMethod()
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(typeSetDone);
}
function typeSetDone() {
   //do something here using the global scripts variable
}
```

You might want to search the [MathJax User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users) for other examples.

Comment: I wanted to be able to pass an argument to the callback method. Your answer does not show how to do this. So I want to use a callback method `function typeSetDone(args) { ...}`

Comment: In that case you'd use `MathJax.Hub.Queue([typeSetDone, arg]);` (or simply use `bind` if you don't have to worry about old IE versions).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. Maybe you could change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Your code worked. Also, I found that following single line of code worked. ` MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element, [typeSetDone,args]]);`. So for passing arguments to callback method just   specify method name following by argument within square brackets as the last part in MathJax.Hub.Queue method call.

Comment: Also, I found that  one can pass multiple arguments to the callback method by using following line of code:`MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element, [typeSetDone,scripts,'123',25]]);`. Here the three parameters being passed to callback method are scripts, '123' and 25. I have tested this on my end.